# C++ Array to Numpy with SWIG Problem with TypeError

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am studying the SWIG for calling C++ libraries in Python. One problem is that when I use 1-dimension array in C++ and want to call it in Python as Numpy arrary, I got the error.

Header file: example.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Example {
  public:
  void say_hello();
  void add(int x, int y, int *result);
  int sub(int *x, int *y);
  void array_add(int *a, int *b, int *c);
};
```

C++ file: example.cpp

```
#include "example.h"

void Example::say_hello() {
    cout<<"Hello Example."<<endl;
}

void Example::add(int x, int y, int *result) {
    *result = x + y;
}

int Example::sub(int *x, int *y) {
    return *x-*y;
}


void Example::array_add(int *a, int *b, int *c) { 
    c[0] = a[0] + b[0]; 
    c[1] = a[1] + b[1]; 
}
```

SWIG interface file: example.i

```
%module example
%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "example.h"
%}

%include "typemaps.i"
%include "numpy.i"
%init %{
   import_array();
%}

%apply int *OUTPUT { int *result };
%apply int *INPUT { int *x, int *y};

%apply int *INPLACE_ARRAY1 {int *a, int *b, int *c};

%include "example.h"
```

Setup file: setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import numpy
import os

example_module = Extension('_example',
    sources=['example.cpp', 'example_wrap.cxx',],
)
setup (
    name = 'example',
    version = '0.1',
    author = "Frank Tang",
    description = """Simple swig C\+\+/Python example""",
    ext_modules = [example_module],
    py_modules = ["example"],
)
```

file: test_example.py
[test_example.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAN8W.png)

After I ran "python test_example.py" I got the error message as follows. I use macOS.

```
(virtualenv) bogon:source tangsg$ python test_example.py 
Hello Example.
7
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_example.py", line 18, in <module>
    example.Example().array_add(a, b, c)
  File "/Users/tangsg/Projects/test/source/example.py", line 115, in 
array_add
    return _example.Example_array_add(self, a, b, c)
TypeError: in method 'Example_array_add', argument 2 of type 'int *'
(virtualenv) bogon:source tangsg$ ›
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPgiW.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error message in text form, not as an image

Comment: Added the error msg in text form

Comment: How is `array_add` going to know the length of these arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your typemaps and your declaration of the `array_add` function are not valid.  NumPy arrays always have a size and this has to be communicated to C++.  There is quite extensive documentation for the usage of [NumPy with SWIG](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.html).

Two other things:

- The function signatures of `add` and `sub` are inefficient.  Rather than using clumsy pointer arguments, just call by value and return a value, i.e.

  ```cpp
    int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
    int sub(int x, int y) { return x - y; }
  ```

  Then you can also remove `%apply int *OUTPUT { int *result };` and `%apply int *INPUT { int *x, int *y};` from the interface file.
- Never ever do `using namespace std;` in a header file! ([Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721))

---

**`example.h`**

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Example {
public:
    void array_add(int *a, int len_a, int *b, int len_b, int *c, int len_c) {
        int const end = std::min(len_a, std::min(len_b, len_c));
        for (int i = 0; i < end; ++i) {
            c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        }
    }
};
```

**`example.i`**

```cpp
%module example
%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
    #include "example.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"
%init %{
   import_array();
%}

%apply (int *IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) { (int *a, int len_a), (int *b, int len_b) };
%apply (int *INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) { (int *c, int len_c) };

%include "example.h"
```

**`test.py`**

```python
import example
import numpy as np
E = example.Example()
a = np.array([1,1], dtype=np.int32)
b = np.array([1,1], dtype=np.int32)
c = np.array([1,1], dtype=np.int32)
E.array_add(a,b,c)
print(c)
```

Example invocation:

```
$ swig -python -c++ example.i
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I/usr/include/python2.7 -fPIC -shared example_wrap.cxx -o _example.so -lpython2.7
$ python test.py
[2 2]
```